# What is wrong with my ask.php Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

So I modified the script as I was instructed earlier, but I am still getting a blank page when I run the HTML form. What is wrong here?

**UPDATE** 2: I get the following error now.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/o/m/o/omorgan/html/dimephysics/adviseme/ask.php on line 32**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

//include('config.php');
//include('open_connection.php');



if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['question']))
    {
        header ("Location: ask.html");
        exit;
    }

    // Database parameters
    $dbhost = '...';
    $dbuser = 'questionme';
    $dbpass = 'Question_2011';
    $dbname = 'questionme';

    $db_name = "questionme";
    $table_name = "questions";

    //Open connection
    $connection = mysql_connect("", "questionme", "Question_2011")
        or die(mysql_error());

    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error())

    $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST[name]);
    $question = mysql_escape_string($_POST[question]);

    //Insert data into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO questions
    (name, question) VALUES
    ('$name', '$question')";

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Ask</title>
<head>
<body>

<h1>Question Submitted</h1>

<p><strong>Name:</strong>
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></p>

<p><strong>Question:</strong>
<?php echo $_POST['question']; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you running this locally? what's the setup? can you update php.ini or at least add **error_reporting(E_ALL);** to your script and then pass us the output?

Comment: and btw... your first row is still without the quotes - that generates a warning stating the constants name and question could not be found (and then saying _using 'name' instead_ and _using 'question' instead_

Comment: Where and how, precisely were you instructed earlier? If you have a previous SO question regarding this code, it would be helpful if you edited your question and provided the link for additional context.

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum you need quotes around your array indexes on this line:

```
if (!isset($_POST[name]) || !isset($_POST[question]))
```

Make it

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['question']))
```

Also, check your error level (can't give you a link at the moment, in a bit of a rush), PHP should be warning you about this.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
if (!isset($_POST[name]) || !isset($_POST[question]))
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['question']))
```

Comment: i get this error when i turn error reporting on: 

Notice: Undefined variable: table_name in /home/content/o/m/o/omorgan/html/dimephysics/adviseme/ask.php on line 23

Answer (score 1):

Place this at the top of the script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

This should let you know whats going on.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: table_name in /home/content/o/m/o/omorgan/html/dimephysics/adviseme/ask.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

Given your error message, it's obvious that your query is failing. You've supressed errors with `@` on it, so the `or die(...)` never kicks in.

Your `$table_name` in the query is undefined, so the query looks like

```
INSERT INTO (name, question) ...
```

which is incorrect SQL.

The two major fixes you need:

1. Remove the `@` supression on mysql_query(). It is almost NEVER acceptable to supress errors, particularly when dealing with a database.
2. Define `$table_name` in your script, or change the variable inside the query string to a proper table name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't check with isset. Since $_POST is always generated you should be using !empty().

Remove @'s before mysql_* commands, this makes your script slow and suppresses helpful errors.

And you are having issues because you don't have table variable set, $table_name needs to be defined.

If you are inserting questions to a table named 'questions' simply change your SQL to:

```
//Insert data into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO `questions` (name, question)
             VALUES ('$name', '$question')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot add a **semicolon** **;** in line no. 30

it should be

```
   $db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of

```
  $db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to end this line:

```
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error())
```

change it to:

```
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```